# Make a switch buttom independent of the component

Tags: reactjs

I make a button to show and hide the TopBar component (toggle), the button was placed on the TopBar.js, (because of the props) I wanna to make this buttom independent, so I can place then on Header.js component, for example (or anywhere).

[image]

----- After click the Switch buttom -----
The TopBar.js disappears. the button fades together:

[image]

header.js component:

```js
imports....

const Header = () => {
  const { site, wpMenu } = useMenuQuery()
  // switch overlay menu
  const [menuOpen, setMenuOpen] = useState(false)

  const handleOverlayMenu = () => {
    setMenuOpen(prev => !prev)
  }
  // switch topBar
  const [topBarOpen, settopBarOpen] = useState(false)

  const handletopBar = () => {
    settopBarOpen(prev => !prev)
  }
  return (
    <>
      <TopBar topBarOpen={topBarOpen} callback={handletopBar} />
      <Wrapper>
        <Content>
          <Link to="/">
            <img src={Logo} alt={site.siteMetadata.title} />
          </Link>
          <Navigation menu={wpMenu.menuItems.nodes} />
          <Hamburger handleOverlayMenu={handleOverlayMenu} />
          <OverlayMenu menuOpen={menuOpen} callback={handleOverlayMenu} />
        </Content>
      </Wrapper>
    </>
  )
}

export default Header
```

topBar.js Component:

```js
imports...

const Topbar = ({ topBarOpen, callback }) => {
  const {
    wpPage: { ACF_HomePage: data }
  } = useTopBarQuery()

  return (
    <TopWrapper topBarOpen={topBarOpen}>
      <Content>
        {data.phone ? (
          <TopItem>
            <GoDeviceMobile size="20" />
            <span>{data.phone}</span>
          </TopItem>
        ) : null}
        {data.whatsapp ? (
          <TopItem>
            <SiWhatsapp size="20" />
            <span>{data.whatsapp}</span>
          </TopItem>
        ) : null}
        {data.adress ? (
          <TopItem>
            <SiGooglemaps size="20" />
            <span>{data.adress}</span>
          </TopItem>
        ) : null}

        <TopButtom onClick={callback}>Switch</TopButtom>
      </Content>
    </TopWrapper>
  )
}

export default Topbar
```

something I put in the topBar styles (styled component):

```js
 display: ${props => (props.topBarOpen ? 'none' : 'block')};
```

I want to leave this button independent, always appearing.

look at that crazy thing:

[Look this video](https://youtu.be/8JJUL-OAdZc)

Answer (score 0):

Solved! creating a separate component and added it in the component header.js

create a folder SwitchButtom. in that folder SwitchButtom.js

```js
import React from 'react'
import { TopButtom } from './SwitchButtom.styles'

const SwitchButtom = ({ handletopBar }) => {
  return <TopButtom onClick={handletopBar}>Mudar</TopButtom>
}

export default SwitchButtom
```

on header.js:

```js
 <SwitchButtom handletopBar={handletopBar} />
```